# PMD-Maven: can't find pmd custom format yyyyMMddhhmm

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, pmd

When I use pmd to analyse my maven project, i met a problem. It tells me 'can't find pmd custom format YYYYmmddhhmm' here is part of my pom.xml

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <targetJdk>1.6</targetJdk>
                    <format>net.com.atos</format>
                    <rulesets>
                        <!--ruleset>/rulesets/basic.xml</ruleset-->
                        <ruleset>/rulesets/informer-ruleset.xml</ruleset>
                    </rulesets>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
</build>
```

There is nearly no documentations about this. Please help me solve it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I wanna say this website is not as good as I have thought.
Almost nobody answers my question everytime.

Then, i would like to say---Yes, i solved it by myself.

The solutions is that we must add xml, because at this case the pmd plugin don't know to use this format by default.
Hope this will help to others who will also stuck with this.